# Binding telerik html5 report to IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

In my project I am trying to integrate Telerik reports. I used below code to bind data to my report:

```
@{
    var typeReportSource = new TypeReportSource() { TypeName = typeof(Invoice).AssemblyQualifiedName };
    typeReportSource.Parameters.Add("OrderNumber", Model.SelectedInvoice);
}

@(
    Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
        .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
        .ReportSource(typeReportSource)
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        .Scale(1.0)
)
```

Now I want to bind a static list to Report that must be generated at controller due to project structure. Is it possible bind Report to static list? I found that  `.ReportSource()` had overload which take `ReportSource` as parameter but it is obsolete now. I tried to use the obsolete method as:

```
 @{
        var reportSource = new Invoice();
        reportSource.DataSource = myData;
    }
    @(
    Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
        .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
        .ReportSource(reportSource)
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        .Scale(1.0)
)
```

but it is shows message `No Report`. Currently I am passing my data as Report Parameter but I think passing large data as report parameter may be a bad practice. Is there any better way to pass static collection to Terik Html5 Report?